# Foreach loop not working as expected - custom tables and references while submitting a form

Tags: wpdb, radio

I have two custom tables and i would like to have a form submission with the name of the redskabs tables to make an reference to my registreringer table. But im confused to how foreach is working in this example.

```
CREATE TABLE $table_registreringer 
    (
        reg_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        dato TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        billedeURL VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        fiske_vaegt INT NOT NULL,
        fiske_laengde INT NOT NULL,         
        reg_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        reg_redskabs_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (reg_id),
        FOREIGN KEY  (reg_user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id),
        FOREIGN KEY  (reg_redskabs_id) REFERENCES $table_redskaber(redskabs_id)
)

CREATE TABLE $table_redskaber 
    (
        redskabs_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        redskabs_navn CHAR (20),
        PRIMARY KEY  (redskabs_id)
)
```

Here is my registration.php page

```
global $wpdb;

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$dato = $_POST['dato'];
$billedeURL = $_POST['billedeURL'];
$fiske_vaegt = trim( $_POST['fiske_vaegt'] );
$fiske_laengde = trim( $_POST['fiske_laengde'] );
// I Don't know how to connect the chosen name to the correspondent ID so that I can use the foreign key and post my registration --  
$redskabsID = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT redskabs_id, redskabs_navn FROM wp_redskaber WHERE redskabs_id = %d", $redskabsID) );

echo $wpdb->show_errors();
$registrering = $wpdb->insert( 
$wpdb->prefix . 'registreringer',
    array(
        'reg_id'            => '',
        'dato'              => $dato,
        'billedeURL'        => $billedeURL,
        'fiske_vaegt'       => $fiske_vaegt,
        'fiske_laengde'     => $fiske_laengde,
        'reg_user_id'       => $current_user->ID,
        'reg_redskabs_id'   => $redskabsID
        ),
    array(
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%d'
        )
    );

}
```

form

```
<form method="post">
    <h3>Registering af din fangst</h3>
    <p><label>længden</label></p>
    <p><input type="number" value="" name="fiske_laengde" id="fiske_laengde" />cm</p>
    <p><label>vægten</label></p>
    <p><input type="number" value="" name="fiske_vaegt" id="fiske_vaegt" />kg</p>
    <p><label>Billede</label></p>
    <p><input type="string" value="" name="billedeURL" id="billedeURL" /></p>
    <p><label>dato</label></p>
    <p><input type="datetime-local" name="dato" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",time($dato)); ?>"/></p>
    <p><label>Fangst udstyr</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" value="1" name="redskaber[]" /></p>
    <p><input type="radio" value="2" name="redskaber[]" /></p>
    <p><input type="radio" value="3" name="redskaber[]" /></p>
```

my foreach code for my radio buttons

```
<?php 

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT redskabs_id, redskabs_navn FROM `wp_redskaber`" );

    $_POST['results'];

    foreach ( $_POST['results'] as $redskaber ) 
    {
        echo $redskaber;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop through `$results`? Why are you using `$_POST['results']`? You don't have any fields named `results`. Do you know the function of [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)?

Comment: I've been trying a lot and used many references but no luck. I've also just looped through $results but im very confused on how to connect the value to my foreign key reference to my table

Comment: It's hard for me to follow along with the code because it's not English, but what are you actually trying to do? I can see in the Insert that you're putting values into the `reg_user_id` and `reg_redskabs_id` column, but I don't know what you're trying to do after that?

Comment: Okay. reg_redskabs_id is of course my reference the table with names i need to let the user choose between before submitting. So what im trying to get with $redskabsID is a ID value with the correct name from the foreach loop. my table is having an ID row and a name row. 

This is where I would love to loop through the names and then give the correct ID to my wpdb->insert

Comment: So to be clear: You want radio button fields for each row in `wp_redskaber`? And the selected radio button should become `reg_redskabs_id` of the insert into `wp_registreringer`?

Comment: Yes that's basically what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first part of your question is just how to get the contents of `wp_redskaber` into radio buttons. As you've attempted, use `$wpdb->get_results();` to query the table. By default each row will be an *Object*, so you'd output it like this:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_redskaber" );

foreach ( $results as $redskaber ) {
    echo sprintf( 
        '<label><input type="radio" name="redskabs_id" value="%s"> %s</label>', 
        esc_attr( $redskaber->redskabs_id ), 
        $redskaber->redskabs_navn
    );
}
```

Because `get_results()` returns an array of objects, you get the id and name of each column with object notation: `$redskaber->redskabs_id`, and `$redskaber->redskabs_nav`.

So I've looped over each result and created a radio button input for each. Radio buttons should all have the same `name`, but different values. In this case I've given them the name `redskabs_id`. Note that I've used [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to put the column values into the HTML. I find this neater than opening and closing strings or PHP tags, but you can do it whatever way you like.

So when the form is submitted you access the selected ID with `$_POST['redskabs_id']`.

So in your second block of code, you set `$redskabsID` to:

```
$redskabsID = $_POST['redskabs_id'];
```

`$wpdb->insert()` will properly escape it for SQL for you, so you're safe there, but for some extra validation you might want to confirm that it's a number with `absint()`:

```
$redskabsID = absint( $_POST['redskabs_id'] );
```

That will get the ID inserted into the `reg_redskabs_id` column. You don't need to do anything special to link them. As long as the ID in that column matches an ID in the `wp_redskaber` table you can match them.

If you're doing some validation and want to be absolutely certain that `$redskabsID` is a valid ID in the `wp_redskaber` table, you can get an array of valid IDs using `$wpdb->get_col()`, and then compare that to the submitted value:

```
global $wpdb;

$valid_redskabs_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT redskabs_id FROM wp_redskaber");

if ( ! in_array( $_POST['redskabs_id'], $valid_redskabs_ids ) ) {
    // Invalid redskabs_id submitted. Handle error here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you i've really been struggling! This helped me so very much. But I have a question why are you using %s in the end of the label? and absint() I know its a reference to absolute Int but I have really heard about it before but it sounds great to double check for validation :)
Again thank you for understanding and help me

Comment: `absint()` makes sure that the value is an integer greater than zero and attempt to extract an integer from any string. In the `sprintf()` call there’s two `%s` one for the ID to use as a value, the other for the name for the label.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense now :) Have a great day!

Comment: If i need to have a dropdown list instead of radio buttons. This is what i've done but it's not giving me the ID for the selected option

`<p><label>Fiskeplads</label></p>
 <select>   <?php  
$lakseplads = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_laksepladser`" );

  foreach ( $lakseplads as $valgplads ) 
  {
   echo sprintf(
   '<option value="reg_laks_id" value="%s"> %s',
   esc_attr( $valgplads->laksepladser_id),
   $valgplads->laksepladser_navn
   );
  }
  ?> 
</select><br>`

Comment: You’re setting two values on each option and not closing the option tag. Your select element is also missing a name.

Comment: I see heh. `'<option value="reg_laks_id"> s%</option>'` So why shouldn't the option tag have a name?

Comment: I figured it out. I just needed a little push :)